# Get rid of columns with null value in json output

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm writing data from dataframe to json file using pandas function .to_json like this:

```
xx.to_json('file_path',orient='records',lines=True)
```

The output of this looks like this:

```
{"speed":null,"state":4.0,"stop_trigger":null,"t":1527237121263,"target_speed":null}
{"speed":null,"state":null,"stop_trigger":null,"t":1527237121264,"target_speed":400.0}
```

How is it possible to get rid of columns in the output if there are null values?:

```
{"state":4.0,"t":1527237121263}
{"t":1527237121264,"target_speed":400.0}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to check every element in the dict and remove the keys which have the null value. It would look something like this.

```
with open('data.json') as f:
    json_dict = json.load(f)
for key in json_dict:
    if json_dict[key] is Null:
         json_dict.pop(key)
```

With `json_dict[key]` you get the value of the key and with the `pop()` function you delete the element from the dictionary. The `pop()` function also returns the value of the key that is going to be deleted.

Comment: This does not work in Python 3: "dictionary changed size during iteration"

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate your dataframe to remove null columns and create a list of dictionaries.

Then use the `json` module to write the list to a file.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 4.0, np.nan, 1527237121263, np.nan],
                   [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 1527237121264, 400.0]],
                  columns=['speed', 'state', 'stop_trigger', 't', 'target_speed'])

d = [dict(row.dropna()) for idx, row in df.iterrows()]

with open('file.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(d, fp)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=singledispatch#functools.singledispatch) is your friend, you can use this to handle `null`/`None` cases in different data types with one function (you can do this on a dataframe, dict, file, or json string).

```
import os
import json
from functools import singledispatch


@singledispatch
def remove_null_bool(ob):
    return ob

@remove_null_bool.register(list)
def _process_list(ob):
    return [remove_null_bool(v) for v in ob if v is not None]

@remove_null_bool.register(dict)
def _process_list(ob):
    return {k: remove_null_bool(v) for k, v in ob.items() if v is not None}



def cleanse(in_file):
    with open(in_file, 'r') as source:
        source_json = json.load(source)
    with open(in_file, 'w') as source:
        json.dump(remove_null_bool(source_json), source)
```